# ItemClickListener у RecyclerView c разными типами данных

Tags: android, recyclerview, onclicklistener, viewholder

Проблема следующая: имеется RecyclerView с разными Holders - в первом TextView, во втором ImageView. Реализовал по образу и подобию как здесь
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Heterogeneous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

Стоит задача, мне кажется, тривиальная - по нажатию на элемент списка показать Toast, что это за элемент (какой Holder нажат), его позицию в списке и удалить данный элемент из списка. Пример из курса, на котором я учусь, сделан под один Holder. Пример содержит `interface OnItemClickListener` с методом `OnItemClick` в адаптере. Затем он передается в holder, где вызывается следующим образом

```
public void setListener(final ContactsAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener) {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onItemClick();
            }
        });
    }
```

Уже в Holder я могу решить две задачи - передать в методе `onItemClick(Holder.class.toString(), position)`, тем самым решив задачу с показом позиции и типом Holdera. Но реализация же этого метода вообще вынесена в MainActivity (по словам преподавателя, так надежнее). Но так у меня получается целая цепочка - MainActivity, Fragment, Adapter, Holder. Правильно ли будет тянуть в MainActivity список объектов из Adapter `List<Object> items`, чтобы добавлять/удалять данные в списке?
И вообще, все примеры, которые я нахожу для добавления удаления элементов, используют один Holder, но я не понимаю, как сделать для нескольких. То, как я думаю это можно реализовать, мне кажется неправильным и сложным. И не могу найти ничего похожего в гугле (скорее всего, неправильно гуглю). Буду очень рад ссылкам на примеры itemClick с несколькими Holders или помощи как сделать обработку на нажатия по этому примеру с Гитхаба. Спасибо!

Comment: Виджет списка в идеале не должен обрабатывать никаких данных, его дело - показывать, логика должна быть в контроллере, то есть в активити. Передавать весь список из адаптера неправильно, вы путаете причину и следствие - это активити передает адаптеру список для отображения, а не наоборот. Соответственно в активити этот список уже есть. Схема такая: в каждом холдере реализуете на клики по виджетам интерфейс обратного вызова , реализация его в активити. Список для изменения берете из активити, после манипуляций, как удаление, новый список передаете в адаптер и обновляете его.

Comment: Для удаления элемента, из адаптера достаточно передавать в активити только позицию удаляемого элемента в списке, при этом использовать один интерфейс обратного вызова для всех холдеров

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ) Если я правильно понял, то я завожу свой List в MainActivity, передаю его во фрагмент и далее в конструктор Адаптера. Также нужно сделать три интерфейса - они получается будут одновременно срабатывать по клику на элемент - один будет удалять и обновлять список, а другие каждый на свой Holder, показывая Toast. Все правильно?

Comment: Если у вас фрагмент, то можно логику делать в фрагменте сразу, зачем таскать что то с активити (вообще зависит конечно от архитектуры приложения вашего). Колбэки не будут срабатывать сразу все, только те, которые привязаны к  виджету на который нажали. Вообще рекомендую почитать книгу, как "Android. Программирование для профессионалов", там все это подробно разбирается и объясняется

Comment: За книгу спасибо, посмотрю обязательно. Но я опять не понял. Вы пишете, что нужно сделать колбеки для разных холдеров, а для удаления единый. Я запутался(

Comment: Нужно сделать один колбэк для удаления, но подключить его к кнопке удаления  в каждом холдере. Один и тот же. Это возможно, потому что колбэк будет отдавать только позицию в списке, эта информация есть для всех холдеров. Если разные холдеры должны отдавать какие то данные, которых нет в другом холдере (например, в одном айтеме есть кнопка поделиться, а в другом такой нет), то тут уже все сложнее в реализации будет.

Comment: Вроде бы понял, спасибо большое!